# Using s3n:// with spark-submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've written a Spark app that is to run on a cluster using `spark-submit`. Here's part of my `build.sbt`.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.1" % "provided" exclude("asm", "asm")
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.6.1" % "provided"
```

`asm` is excluded because I'm using another library which depends on a different version of it. The `asm` dependency in Spark seems to come from one of Hadoop's dependents, and I'm not using the functionality.

The problem now is that with this setup, `saveToTextFile("s3n://my-bucket/dir/file")` throws `java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: s3n`.

Why is this happening? Shouldn't `spark-submit` provide the Hadoop dependencies?

I've tried a few things:

- Leaving out `"provided"`
- Putting `hadoop-aws` on the classpath, via a jar and `spark.executor.extraClassPath` and `spark.driver.extraClassPath`. This requires doing the same for all of its transitive dependencies though, which can be painful.

Neither really works. Is there a better approach?

I'm using the pre-built `spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6`.